# Refreshing a page after another tab has closed

Tags: javascript, tabs

I am having an issue with refreshing a page when another tab has been closed. Strangely enough this only seems to work fine on internet explorer however when I try using other browsers such as chrome and firefox it seems to freeze?

```
    var window;
    win = window.open(event.url, foobar);
    while(window) {
        if(win.closed){
            location.reload();
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is inside of the main home tab.

Comment: Also in the code the variable is actually called win not window sorry for the typo.
var window is actually var win